# Why does using [H|T] as a parameter instead of a normal variable cause my predicate to fail?

Tags: list, prolog

I'm creating a predicate to remove a specified element from a list so remove(Xs,X,Ys) should hold if Ys is the result of removing all occurrences
of X from Xs. My initial failing predicate is shown below:

```
remove([],_,[]).
remove([H1|T1],H1,[H2|T2]) :- % e.g. [2,3] , 2, [3]
   remove(T1,H1,[H2|T2]).     % remove first head -> [3], 2, [3]
remove([H1|T1],Y,[H1|T2]) :-  % heads match e.g. [1,2,3], 2, [1,3]
   H1\==Y,
   remove(T1,Y,T2).           % remove heads -> [2,3], 2, [3]
```

This was failing but then I noticed that I had a redundant `[H2|Y2]` where I could have just used a variable e.g. `Ys`. I made this change thinking that it would still fail but instead it starting working. The working code is shown below:

```
remove([],_,[]).
remove([H1|T1],H1,Ys) :-      % e.g. [2,3] , 2, [3]
   remove(T1,H1,Ys).          % remove first head -> [3], 2, [3]
remove([H1|T1],Y,[H1|T2]) :-  % heads match e.g. [1,2,3], 2, [1,3]
   H1\==Y,
   remove(T1,Y,T2).           % remove heads -> [2,3], 2, [3]
```

Can someone explain why changing `[H2|T2]` to `Ys` made it work?

Comment: @CapelliC Are you using SWI-Prolog? The test query remove([1,2,3,2],2,[1,3]) returns false using my first code and true using the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in the progression of the query, the pattern, `remove([H|T], H, [])` is coming up which will match the head of the second clause of your second version, `remove([H1|T1], H1, Ys)`, but will not match the head of the second clause of your first version, `remove([H1|T1], H1, [H2|T2])`.

If you run trace on the query, `remove([1, 2, 3, 2], 2, [1, 3])` using your first program version, you get:

```
   Call: (6) remove([1, 2, 3, 2], 2, [1, 3]) ? creep
   Call: (7) 1\==2 ? creep
   Exit: (7) 1\==2 ? creep
   Call: (7) remove([2, 3, 2], 2, [3]) ? creep
   Call: (8) remove([3, 2], 2, [3]) ? creep
   Call: (9) 3\==2 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 3\==2 ? creep
   Call: (9) remove([2], 2, []) ? creep
   Fail: (9) remove([2], 2, []) ? creep   <---- NOTE THIS FAILURE! (no clause match)
   Fail: (8) remove([3, 2], 2, [3]) ? creep
   Redo: (7) remove([2, 3, 2], 2, [3]) ? creep
   Fail: (7) remove([2, 3, 2], 2, [3]) ? creep
   Fail: (6) remove([1, 2, 3, 2], 2, [1, 3]) ? creep
```

The case `remove([2], 2, [])` will not match the second clause of your first implementation:

```
remove([H1|T1], H1, [H2|T2])...
```

So `H1 = 2`, `T1 = []`, but `[H2|T2]` is not unifiable with `[]`.

But it will match the second clause of your second implementation:

```
remove([H1|T1], H1, Ys).
```

Here you get, `H1 = 2`, `T1 = []`, and `Ys = []`. Here it is in the trace for your second version:

```
[trace]  ?- remove([1,2,3,2],2,[1,3]).
   Call: (6) remove([1, 2, 3, 2], 2, [1, 3]) ? creep
   Call: (7) 1\==2 ? creep
   Exit: (7) 1\==2 ? creep
   Call: (7) remove([2, 3, 2], 2, [3]) ? creep
   Call: (8) remove([3, 2], 2, [3]) ? creep
   Call: (9) 3\==2 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 3\==2 ? creep
   Call: (9) remove([2], 2, []) ? creep   <---- SUCCESS! (2nd clause match)
   Call: (10) remove([], 2, []) ? creep   <---- SUCCESS!
   Exit: (10) remove([], 2, []) ? creep
   Exit: (9) remove([2], 2, []) ? creep
   Exit: (8) remove([3, 2], 2, [3]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) remove([2, 3, 2], 2, [3]) ? creep
   Exit: (6) remove([1, 2, 3, 2], 2, [1, 3]) ? creep
```